# ICS Bluetooth Losing Connectivity

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, bluetooth

I have a Galaxy S2 Skyrocket on AT&T that is currently running Nexus ICS Zero Build 2 Rev.12.

I've been trying to pair the phone with my car. It will initially connect, but when I try to either use the phone or a music player, the bluetooth disconnects quickly. I've read about this happening to many people using ICS, but haven't found a solution.

Is there another ICS ROM that would work better for Bluetooth? Am I better off going back to GB?

Let me know if you need more info.